# Does the U.S. Constitution place any limitations on how long a U.S. President can be on vacation?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-president

I am curious to know if the U.S. Constitution places any limitations on how long a U.S. President can be on vacation.

Comment: Shows no research

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not directly

However, a President who is unable to discharge their duties (by being on vacation or otherwise) can be dealt with by either:

- the vice-President and Cabinet invoking the 25th amendment and declaring the President unable to perform their duties,
- by the House impeaching the President for the “high crime and misdemeanour” of not doing her job. If convicted by the Senate, the person is no longer President.

Comment: there is something to be said that for certain Presidents, the less time they are in the office, the better.